# "if (upPressed) {object.y -= 10;}" - stacks after each death

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a game in class, and i can't figure this out.
Whenever my character loses, the game jumps to the "try again"-screen. When i press the button to gotoAndPlay(1), the code "Rakett.Rita.y -= 10;" stacks, making the object move twice as fast next time.
I've tried unloading the MC, load another scene instead of another frame, and various other things. I can't get it to work.

Also, whenever i press enter, the tween i use for objects crashes. Is there any way to disable the enter press?

Thanks!
Here's my code:

```
var upPressed: Boolean = false;      
var downPressed: Boolean = false;
var leftPressed: Boolean = false;
var rightPressed: Boolean = false;

RakettRita.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey_2);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed_2);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed_2);
```

ADDED^

```
function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey_2(event: Event) {

if (upPressed) {
    RakettRita.y -= 10;
    RakettRita.rotation = -20;
}
if (downPressed) {
    RakettRita.y += 10;
    RakettRita.rotation = 40;

}   
// if hit
if (trær.hitTestPoint(RakettRita.x, RakettRita.y, true)) {
// Go to losing-screen
gotoAndStop(215)
    }

}

function fl_SetKeyPressed_2(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
switch (event.keyCode) {
    case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = true;
            break;
        }
    case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = true;
            break;
        }

}
}

function fl_UnsetKeyPressed_2(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
switch (event.keyCode) {
    case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = false;
            break;
        }
    case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = false;
            break;
        }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove these event listeners when you get to the try again screen. Otherwise next time this frame's code runs, it's going to add a copy of the listeners and everything will happen twice.

Comment: That sounds logical! Do you know how i do this? This is my first AS3 script.

Comment: You remove the event listeners just like you added them. You probably did something like: addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, yourFunction). So you need to do removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,yourFunction).

Comment: Tried adding this code in the frames where you either win or loose, but it didn't work. I also added the rest of the code in my orginal post. What did i do wrong? Thanks so much for your help!
RakettRita.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey_2);
stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed_2);
stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed_2);

Comment: There we go! I solved it by adding the removEevenLlisteners in the IF-statement on the orginal frame. Thank you so much!